# Making visible and refreshing a DOM element : Angular JS

Tags: javascript, jquery, angularjs

Not very familiar with Angular JS but here is what I have and what I want:

```
<div ng-app="MyApp" ng-controller="appController"> 
   <div class="input-group">
     <input class="form-control enableEnter" type="text" ng-model="action"/>
      <div class="input-group-btn">
        <button class="btn btn-primary" ng-click="search()">Search</button>
      </div>
   </div>   
   <ul class="dropdown-menu" id="list" ng-show = {{display}} >
        <li> hello </li>
        <li class="dropdown" ng-repeat="x in actions">
            {{x.name}}
        </li>
    </ul>
</div>
```

My js file :

```
MyApp.controller('appController', ['$scope', function ($scope) {
    $scope.actions = [];
    $scope.display=false;
    $scope.search = function () {
        $.get("http://localhost:8080/get/something/" + $scope.action)
            .success(function (response) {
                console.log(response);
                $scope.actions = response['RESPONSE'];
                $scope.display=true;
            }).error(function (jqXHR, textStatus, errorThrown) {
                console.error("Error retrieving something list", textStatus, errorThrown);
            });
    }
}]);
```

The `$scope.actions` is empty initialized in the controller however on clicking the "Submit" button , we get a list of actions which are populated in `actions`. I want to show this list below the form. For this I am changing the value of `ng-show` when submit is clicked. Should this automatically update the `<UL>` element? Because I can't seem to see anything even after clicking.

Comment: Are you getting data in response? Something looks strange.

Comment: Yes I am getting data in response. I doesn't seem to refresh the DOM

Answer (score 1):

You don't need to interpolate `{{ }}` inside an `ng-show`:

```
<ul class="dropdown-menu" id="list" ng-show="display" >
    <li> hello </li>
    <li class="dropdown" ng-repeat="x in actions">
        {{x.name}}
    </li>
</ul>
```

You might also want to look into an [ng-if](https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/directive/ngIf) as well.

Comment: ng-if should be to evaluate conditional statements which does not fit my case. I simply want to update the DOM every time I click and the actionsList is overwritten. Though after correcting to "display" it seems to be working , but i need to click twice for it to update and reflect. It doesn't reflect on a single click.

Comment: `ng-show` and `ng-if` are used to evaluate conditionals.  Two-way binding will automatically update the `actions`, so you probably don't need either `ng-show` or `ng-if`.  Have you tried to get rid of `ng-show`?

Comment: You need to click twice because you are re-assiging `$scope.actions`.  First, it is bound to `[]` and then you are re-assigning it: `$scope.actions = response['RESPONSE'];`.  You need to `push` the actions into the existing array.

Answer (score 0):

Problem is in below statement

```
<ul class="dropdown-menu" id="list" ng-show = {{display}} >

`change ng-show= {{display}} to ng-show='display'`
```

Check this working example - In this example, I have created submit button after clicking on ,I have change value of display and stored some dummy data.

https://jsfiddle.net/Shital_D/fc0L5pe3/2/